# Remove all occurrences of a number in an array in C++

Tags: c++

Supposed we passed in the array {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}, and we wanted to
    remove all occurrences of the number 3.  The resulting array would be
    {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, and the return value would be 5, because there are now
    only 5 items in the array.
**This function is wrong. I don't know how to remove the occurrences. I know my index holds the positions of the occurrences. So i need to delete those positions from my array. HELP!!**
I can only use arrays, i cannot use vectors or pointers.

```
void test() {

    int data[] = { 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4, 9 };
    int length = 10;
    int x = 2;
    int index = 0;
    int counter =0;


    int tempIndex = 0;
    int finalLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (x != data[i]) {

            tempIndex = i;
            counter++;
            cout << "Array: " << tempIndex << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "Size: " << counter << endl;
}
```

Comment: Supposed we have [std::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) for that.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere? That's what these forums do, answer questions.

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask a question, is it not working?

Comment: Sorry, I am new. It is not working. It is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. How do I delete the occurrences from my array?

Comment: The easiest way without many concepts known is to have a for loop that goes over your array and you create a vector before hand and push back all numbers that are not equal to the number you don't want, then print out vector.size(), something like vector<int> new_numbers; for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) { if( array[i] != number_I_dont_want) { new_numbers.push_back(array[i]) } cout << "Array size = " << new_numbers.size()";

Comment: I cannot use a vector, I can only use arrays :(

Comment: Reconsider the position of the second for loop, and its limits.

Comment: That's the part I am having trouble with. in my code I have a for loop that goes through my array and then i stored the position of the concurrences in my variable index. The issues is that I don't now how to delete those numbers at those given positions from my array.

Comment: @ClaudioAlfaro -- Arrays cannot be resized, so your requirement as to what the array should look like is impossible to solve.  The only thing you can do is replace elements in an array with a certain value, but you can't shrink or expand an array.  That is what a `std::vector` is for -- dynamic resizing.

Comment: You don't *delete*, you move the values from the right by one, thus replacing the *deleted* value by the next one. For example, with the first `3` of: `{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1},`, the array becomes `{1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, X}`. (We don't care anymore of the last value *X*).

Comment: Yes, delete was not a right word. I am trying to have an output with out the occurrences.

Comment: The size of a C-style array can't be resized. You need to create a new one to store the new data.

Comment: @ClaudioAlfaro -- This entire problem and the way you want to solve it is an example of learning how to walk by standing on your heels.   You want to create a new array -- so how do you propose to do that?  Then you want to shrink an array.  How do you propose to do that?  All of this is simple using `std::vector`, but the issue becomes more complicated if your requirement is you only can use arrays and "no pointers".  I would say it is impossible *without* using pointers if you don't want to use `vector`.

Comment: @O'Neil yes how do Implement that in code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes. but unfortunately I can use a vector or pointer. I am new to C++ and I probably don't have the right words to express my problem. I apollogize.

Comment: @ClaudioAlfaro -- If your goal is to create a new array, you can't do it without using pointers, since `new` returns a pointer.  So if you want my opinion, you are beingasked to do the impossible.

Comment: This is more or less what your second for loop does.

Comment: For starters, your function won't be returning anything if it's a `void` type.

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of std::remove function available in C++ you can do something like below

```
int data[] = { 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4, 9 };
int length = 10;
int* pbegin = myints; 
int* pend = data+sizeof(data)/sizeof(int);                     

pend = std::remove (pbegin, pend, 3);    
for (int* p=pbegin; p!=pend; ++p)
   std::cout << *p;
```

Comment: I think the little start means pointers right? I cant use pointers.

Comment: yes its a pointer pointing to an element in the array

Comment: I can't use pointers. in my code I have a for loop that goes through my array and then i stored the position of the concurrences in my variable index. The issues is that I don't now how to delete those numbers at those given positions from my array.

Comment: can you use std:array data type instead int[]. If yes then still you can use the same code with little change to achieve the same

Comment: what do you mean? it has to be an array of integer.

Comment: @ClaudioAlfaro -- Read my comment in the main section.  You **can't** resize arrays.

Comment: I'm not trying to resize the array I am just trying to return a value without the occurrences. Maybe deleting was not the appropriate word. But I am trying to copy the array without the occurrences.

Comment: what i meant was instead of using int data[] you can use std::array<int, 10> as your data type

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said until they were blue in the face (probably) you **cannot** resize arrays. The memory is fixed. What you **can** do is keep track of matching elements that you want to "remove" and shift the remaining elements to make it appear that they have been removed. The reality will be that the array in memory will still be the size you started with, but you can print the results using the computed size of your "new" array.

The following code should do what you want. The first argument is your data array, the next argument will be the fixed size of said array. The last argument is the number you want to "remove" all occurrences of. The function `remove_match` will return the size of your data array minus any matches it found. The array will be shifted such that only the non-matching elements will be shown if you were to print the resulting array using the return value as it's new size.

```
int remove_match(int array[], int length, int match)
{
    size_t shift(0);
    int removed(0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (array[i] == match)
        {
            removed++;
        }
        else
        {
            array[shift++] = array[i];
        }
    }
    return (length - removed);
}
```

You would invoke this function like this for example

```
int match = 2;
int data[] = { 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4, 9 };
int length = 10;

int newLength = remove_match(data, length, match);

// validate your results
for(int i = 0; i < newLength; ++i)
{
    std::cout << data[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Using more of the standard library your entire function body can be rewritten as `return std::distance(array, std::remove(array, array + length, match));`

Comment: @Blastfurnace Excellent but given all the constraints OP has listed I was guessing the standard library algorithms are off the table.  Otherwise why are we even using C-style arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize a C-style array without creating a new one. It is fixed. If you are looking for counting occurrence of a particular element and tracking the sum of the new data, then you could simply do

```
void test() {

    int data[] = { 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4, 9 };
    int length = 10;
    int x = 2;
    //int index =0;
    int sum(0);

    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (x == data[i]) {
            //index = i;
            //--counter; //return # of ocurrences in array
            //cout << "Position of ocurrences: " << index << endl;
            ++counter;
        }else{
            sum += data[i];
        }
    }
    //for (int a = counter; a < length; a++) {
        //data[a] = data[a + 1];
        //cout <<"testing"<< data[a];
    //}

    cout << "Number of ocurences: " << counter << " sum: " << sum << endl;
}
```

Another approach is to assign the repeated element with zero but this will not resize the array but rather it eliminates the repeated one. This is a workaround approach but it modifies the original data.

Comment: I didn't quite get the I can't risize the array in C. However, I found a solution: void test() {

 int data[] = { 2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 7, 8, 4, 9 };
 int length = 10;
 int x = 2;
 int index = 0;
 int counter =0;


 int tempIndex = 0;
 int finalLength = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
  if (x != data[i]) {

   tempIndex = i;
   counter++;
   cout << "Array: " << tempIndex << endl;
  }
 }
 cout << "Size: " << counter << endl;

 
}

Comment: @ClaudioAlfaro, well, this is the rule of the language. May be you need to handle the problem from different angle.